# WhatsApp contact has wrong name associated with it in contacts (but correct name within WhatsApp itself) - How to fix?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

In setting up my new Samsung S4 mini one contact (guy) got confused with another (girl). When the girl would phone me, I'd see the guy's picture (via google) and name. Somehow I changed the number and saved the girl as a separate new entry. Along the way, I must have done something wrong, cuz as a result I've now got the following entries in contacts:

- guy: `Phone`, `Google`, `WhatsApp`
- girl: `Phone`, `Google`
- (same) **guy**'s name: `WhatsApp` of the **girl** ( ! )

In contrast, within `WhatsApp` itself, the names of the guy & girl are correct.

How to fix?

---

PS: If I try to delete the *guy's name girl's `WhatsApp`* contact, I get the following message popup:

> You cannot delete contacts from **read-only** accounts, but you can hide
>   them in your contacts lists.

Comment: see also [WhatsApp Help Center - How to delete a contact](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23179277)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. 
I followed following steps which resolved the issue.

1. Removed the WhatsApp from Setting-->Account (no Impact on whatsApp).
2. Removed the Google account & added back.

This solved my problem.

Comment: For me, it was Settings > Accounts > Other Accounts > WhatsApp > WhatsApp > More > <Uncheck Contacts> > Remove account

Answer (score 1):

Go to your contact list and select the girl's contact,

Hit *Edit* - the icon that looks like a pen

Then *Settings* - three dots on the top right corner
and choose "Join"

This will take you back to your contact list. From here choose the correct What's app id

Answer (score 1):

The problem on an Android phone could be that you inappropriately merged two contacts for two different people into one.

The solution that worked for me was to delete both person's contacts on the Google contacts list and on the cell phone contacts list. Sometimes one person can be listed twice or more times in your contact list so all of their listings need to be removed. Then add the two people back to the google contact list making sure not to have any overlapping phone numbers. Overlapping phone numbers is what caused the inappropriate merging in the first place.

To delete and add to the Google contact list:

1. Open up Google Chrome.
2. Click on the 9-dots in the upper-right hand corner.
3. Scroll down in the pop-up box until you get to contacts
4. Click on contacts.
5. Type in person's phone number with area code.
6. Click on person's name.
7. Click on 3-vertical-dots in upper right hand corner.
8. Click delete.
9. Click delete in the new pop-up box.
10. Repeat for all contacts sharing same phone number used in the WhatsApp app. 10. Add back the contacts by clicking on the rainbow-colored cross in the upper left corner.