# Incorrect name on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When someone saves my coordinates using WhatsApp, They see a wrong name which is being reflected as Default ( Probably an old short name of mine), how do I correct this issue. I use an Android Phone ( Pixel 6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WhatsApp contact has wrong name associated with it in contacts (but correct name within WhatsApp itself) - How to fix?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54311/whatsapp-contact-has-wrong-name-associated-with-it-in-contacts-but-correct-name)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, on Whatsapp, the name comes from their contact list.  If they add you for the first time, then it defaults to whatever you have called yourself.  The photo however comes from your account.

- To change the name, the recipient has to do it in their contact list.
- If it's a Group Name, and if you are an admin, then you can change the group name.
- If they have not changed the name, then it is possible that it will change if you change it.

  1. Start WhatsApp
  2. Press the three dot menu
  3. Press Settings
  4. Press your photo
  5. Press on the pen icon next to your name